# Updating a React list without re-rendering said list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out how to render out a set of divs, without re-rendering the entire list as a new set is added.

So I've got a stateful component. Inside said stateful component, I've got a function that A, gets a list of post id's, and B, makes a request to each of those post id's and pushes the results to an array. Like so:

```
getArticles = () => {
        axios.get(`${api}/topstories.json`)
             .then(items => {
                let articles = items.data;
                let init = articles.slice(0,50);
                init.forEach(item => {
                    axios.get(`${post}/${item}.json`)
                         .then(article => {
                             this.setState({ articles: [...this.state.articles, article.data]});
                    });
            })
        });
}
```

Then, I've got a second function that takes this information and outputs it to a list of posts. Like so:

```
mapArticles = () => {
        let articles = this.state.articles.map((item, i) => {
            let time = moment.unix(item.time).fromNow();
            return(
                <section className="article" key={i}>
                    <Link className="article--link" to={`/posts/${item.id}`}/>
                    <div className="article--score">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="angle-up"/>
                        <p>{item.score}</p>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="angle-down"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="article--content">
                        <div className="article--title">
                            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="article--meta">
                            {item.by} posted {time}. {item.descendants ? `${item.descendants} comments.` : null} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="article--external">
                        <a href={item.link} target="_blank">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="external-link-alt"/>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </section>
            )
        });
        return articles;
    }
```

I then use `{this.mapArticles()}` inside the render function to return the appropriate information.

However, whenever the app loads in a new piece of data, it re-renders the entire list, causing a ton of jank. I.e., when the first request finishes, it renders the first div. When the second request finishes, it re-renders the first div and renders the second. When the third request finishes, it re-renders the first and second, and renders the third.

Is there a way to have React recognize that the div with that key already exists, and should be ignored when the state changes and the function runs again?

Comment: re-rendering itself should not be an issue since it's native for React. I guess you have call to `getArticles()` from the inside of `render()` or other methods called in `render()`. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

A technique that I use to only render the part that are new is to keep a cache map of already drawn obj, so in the render method I only render the new incoming elements.

Here is an example:
Take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/wq2vq09pr7

In this code you can see that the List has an cache array and the render method 
only draw new arrays

```
class RealTimeList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cache = [];
  }
  renderRow(message, key) {
    return <div key={key}>Mesage:{key}</div>;
  }
  renderMessages = () => {
    //let newMessages=this,props.newMessage
    let newElement = this.renderRow(this.props.message, this.cache.length);
    this.cache.push(newElement);
    return [...this.cache];
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div> Smart List</div>
        <div className="listcontainer">{this.renderMessages()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message: "hi" };
  }

  start = () => {
    if (this.interval) return;
    this.interval = setInterval(this.generateMessage, 200);
  };
  stop = () => {
    clearTimeout(this.interval);
    this.interval = null;
  };

  generateMessage = () => {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMilliseconds();
    this.setState({ title: n });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.start}> Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.stop}> Stop</button>
        <RealTimeList message={this.state.message} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If items arrive at the same time, wait till all items are fetched, then render:

```js
getArticles = () => {
    axios.get(`${api}/topstories.json`)
      .then(items => {
          let articles = items.data;
          let init = articles.slice(0, 50);
          Promise.all(init.map(item => axios.get(`${post}/${item}.json`)).then(articles => {
              this.setState({
                articles
              });
            })
          });
      }
```

If you really want to render immediately after an item is fetched, you can introduce a utility component that renders when promise resolves.

```js
class RenderOnResolve extends React.Component {
    state = null
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.promise.then(data => this.setState(data))
    }
    render() {
      return this.state && this.props.render(this.state);
    }
  }

  // usage:

  <RenderOnResolve promise={promise} render={this.articleRenderer}/>
```